# HNSW: meaning of "length scale" and "characteristic radius"

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour, graph-theory

I'm reading through the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.09320.pdf) behind the well known Hierarchical Navigable
Small World (HNSW) graphs for approximate nearest neighbor search, but I don't understand one of the core concepts.

> The idea of Hierarchical NSW algorithm is to separate the links according to their length scale into different layers and then search in a multilayer graph.

[image]

What does "length scale" mean? Does "characteristic radius" mean the same thing? Does "length scale" refer to the number of edges between two vertices or does it refer to the distance measured by the user specified distance metric, like cosine or euclidean distance? I'm working on an image similarity search project, and when I use non-graph-based approximate-nearest-neighbor methods like random projections I measure the similarity (or distance) between two vectors based on their cosine similarity.

Comment: There's surprisingly very little that explains HNSW, and most explanations I see in videos or on blog posts just gloss over the paper. Have you found the answers to your questions? Have you found anything that explains the paper better/in a more easy to understand fashion?